# How to install next-js with react 17?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

How I can install next.js with React 17? When I type:
npx create-next-app --ts, npx installed Next with React 18, but I can't use React 18, because Stripe not working at the moment with R18 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to use an older version of Next JS.

The latest one I can see with React 17 is 12.1.2, so you can start your project with the following:

```
npx create-next-app@12.1.2
```

You can check the release change logs for Next JS here:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases

Comment: I just used the command `npx create-next-app@12.1.2` and it still installed with react and react-dom dependencies version 18.2.0.

Comment: Yeah I think this is currently bugged see here
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35794

Answer (score 16):

If you've already created the project:

#### NPM

remove new versions:

```
npm uninstall next react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom
```

install old versions:

```
npm install next@12.1.2 react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2
npm install -D @types/react@17.0.2 @types/react-dom@17.0.2
```

#### Yarn

```
yarn remove next react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom 
yarn add next@12.1.2 react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2
yarn add -D @types/react@17.0.2 @types/react-dom@17.0.2
```

Comment: For yarn it's `yarn remove`, `yarn add` and `yarn add -D`. If you opted for JavaScript (instead of TypeScript) you want to skip the two @types packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative approach , first create a new nextjs typescript project using    `npx create-next-app@latest --ts`
. And then copied the versions of all the dependencies and devDependencies to package.json . after replacing the version delete node_modules folder and package-lock.json file . after that run this command `npm install` .

Here is a sample package.json. I got this after create new nextjs project.

```
   {
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.2.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.7.1",
    "@types/react": "18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "eslint": "8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.4",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}
```